# Querying a Firestore Collection for a Property’s membership of a given Array

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

Say, I have an array with values

```
types = ['jay', 'pigeon', 'crow', 'peacock']
```

which I’d like to use to do a query on the Firestore collection `birds` based on whether the document property `type` is contained in it.

So from

```
groaney: {
  ...
  type: 'crow'
  ...
},
chirpie: {
  ...
  type: 'chick'
  ...
},
jeery: {
  ...
  type: 'jay'
  ...
}
```

we’re supposed to get

```
groaney: {
  ...
  type: 'crow'
  ...
},
jeery: {
  ...
  type: 'jay'
  ...
}
```

I realize that I could do the query for the individual elements separately

```
Promise.all(
  types.map(t =>
    firebase.firestore().collection('birds')
      .where('type', '==', t)
      .get()
  )
)
```

and then combine the results. However, I’d much rather do it in one fell swoop using a single `where()` since doing a `Promise.all()` on a bunch of firestore collection `where`s looks like a waste of resources to me.

Is there an elegant/efficient way to achieve this?

(As a quick aside, note that when it comes to the inverse problem, that is querying a collection for the array membership of a single value, we have `where('types', 'array-contains', type)` to the rescue.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, there was an IN query added to Firestore back in 2019 to achieve exactly that.
https://firebase.blog/posts/2019/11/cloud-firestore-now-supports-in-queries/